# Running netlogo headless and repeat the experiment

Tags: netlogo, repeat, headless

I plan to run my model on a cluster so I can repete the run (at least 40 times) on multiple cores.  I found usefull info on stack, on the netlogo website but I don't see the codes lines to speficy the number of repetitions ? Is it something like `--repetition 40`  ?

```
--model ~/myproject/MyModel.nlogo \
--experiment MyExperiment \
--threads 8
--Dnetlogo.extensions.dir="path"
```

Comment: The number of repetitions is in the experiment definition.

Comment: Thank you Seth. Ok, so know I understand better! I have to set up an experiment in Behaviour Space, than save the model, open it in NotePad and then I have the structure of "myexperiment" file that must be saved in .xlm extension, in the same folder of the model, I guess. Many thanks, it is clearer!

Comment: Hi again Seth, I wrote another question related to this, I don't know if you have a comment regarding it ? That would be very helpful !!   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74728742/netlogo-headless-exporting-world-at-each-steps